# What is the alternative of fetching multiple queries in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm actually a bit confused about the Eloquent and how it works. i just want to know the way im on is not a bad practice or kind of overhead for the `Eloquent` ORM. 
this is part of my `Classroom` model

```
static function classgradeList(){
    return Classroom::select('classgrade')
        ->groupBy('classgrade')
        ->orderBy('classgrade')
        ->get();
}
static function classsectionList(){
    return Classroom::select('classgrade','classsection')
        ->groupBy('classgrade','classsection')
        ->orderBy('classsection')
        ->get();
}
static function classnameList(){
    return Classroom::select('classgrade','classsection','classname')
        ->orderBy('classname')
        ->get();
}
```

The reason behind these functions is to create list for 3 separate area on same view. i then call them like below in the same view:

```
<ul id="classsections" class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach(App\Classroom::classsectionList() as $csect)
                <li onclick="csselect(this)" data-cg="{{$csect->classgrade}}" data-cs="{{$csect->classsection}}" class="classsection">
                    <a>{{$csect->classsection}}</a>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>

 <ul id="classgrades" class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach(App\Classroom::classgradeList() as $cgrade)
                <li onclick="cgselect(this);" data-cg="{{$cgrade->classgrade}}" >
                    <a>{{$cgrade->classgrade}}</a>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>

<ul id="classnames" class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach(App\Classroom::classnameList() as $item)
                <li onclick="cnselect(this)" data-cg="{{$item->classgrade}}" data-cs="{{$item->classsection}}" data-cn="{{$item->classname}}" class="classname">
                    <a>{{$item->classname}}</a>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
```

I think this code will have way overhead, i want to implement it in a better way like fetching all the things once and do query on it in `php` scope and eventually through sth like `Builder` laravel's native class.

Comment: Instead of using static functions, you can use query scopes in your model.  If you have a bunch of different ways you're grouping items, there may not be a better solution than running three queries, but if there are a limited number of items, you could try grouping them using Laravel's collection methods instead.  All of which are documented on laravel.com/docs.

Comment: Thanks for the query scopes, ok then i go the query way for now.

Comment: @Devon actually i tested the collection too, but it's impossible to pass array to `groupBy()` of Collection cause the `groupby` arg is `Callable\String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Devon's comment i've overcome the problem with the collection, i had a bit of problem with groupBy function of Collection which couldn't take array of columns, for that i made another column for collection which is combination of two target columns like below.

```
$allClass->map(function ($classroom) {
        $classroom['sectgrade'] = $classroom['classgrade'].".".$classroom['classsection'];
        return $classroom;
    });
```